# What kind of number is $2^\sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

What kind of number is $2^\sqrt{2}$ ? It is real and obviously is not integer nor rational. Is it real algebraic number?

Comment: This is the [Gelfond Schneider constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant).  It is transcendental.

Comment: @pasaba por aqui Try to use logarithm.

Comment: @HarshKumar How is that going to help?

Comment: @SimpleArt I think it will bring the power in multiplication $log 2^\sqrt2=\sqrt2 \times log2 $

Comment: @HarshKumar Sure, but what does that tell us?  Nothing is so clear.

Comment: @SimpleArt It will tell us that $2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational.

Comment: @HarshKumar No, it tells us that the log of that is irrational, depending on which base you used for the log.  To show that $2^{\text{irrational}}\implies\text{irrational}$ is a whole 'nother step.

Comment: @SimpleArt Can't I take antilog

Comment: @HarshKumar But what does that tell you about the number?  Without the Gelfon-Schneider theorem, it tells us nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), since $2$ and $\sqrt2$ are both algebraic with $a\ne0,1$ and $\sqrt2$ irrational, it follows that $2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational and transcendental.

Your exact number is also known as the [Gelfond-Schneider constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant), and it has its own Wikipedia full of such information.

Comment: It doesn't have its own Wikipedia. It has, however, its own _page on_ Wikipedia :)

Comment: @Wojowu Oh, whatever